# Why I'm getting this error?HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, post

I've create the DB, And the table name is 1.employee(master), 2.department. I've use the SQL inner join method to display the results in join format. then I'm trying to update the employee table, I'm getting this kind of error.

the error was:

```
>     HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
>     
>     type Exception report
>     
>     message Servlet execution threw an exception
>     
>     description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>     
>     exception 
>     
>     javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     
>     root cause 
>     
>     java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:      

>     setDep_id cannot be resolved or is not a field
>     
>   com.controller.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:85)    
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

And in the error is following line as:

1.controller.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    User user=new User();
    user.setEmpName(request.getParameter("empName"));
    user.setEmpAddress(request.getParameter("empAddress"));
    user.setDep_id(request.getParameter("dep_id"));

    String emp_id=request.getParameter("emp_id");
        if(emp_id!=null && !emp_id.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            user.setEmp_id(Integer.parseInt(emp_id));
            dao.updateUser(user);
        }
        else
        {
            dao.addUser(user);
        }
    RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(EMPLOYEE_LIST);
    request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
    view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

2.User.java :

```
package;
class

    public int dep_id;

    public int getDep_id()
    {
        return dep_id;
    }
    public void setDep_id(int dep_id)
    {
        this.dep_id=dep_id;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "User[emp_id="+emp_id+"]";
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `setDep_id cannot be resolved or is not a field` means? You can see exactly where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the `Dep_id` by assign the value directly.

You have to pass the value to the `setDep_id` method as:

```
//first you need to cast to int because request.getParameter("dep_id") return a String
int depId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dep_id"))
user.setDep_id(depId );
```

Comment: I've change that one, no different form the output. now also I'm getting same error @Juba

Answer (score 1):

Because here:

```
user.setDep_id=request.getParameter("dep_id");
```

you are writing into an non-existing field. You do define a setter though:

```
user.setDep_id(request.getParameter("dep_id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

See, whenever there is  HTTP Status 500 status, there is somewhere we have written a wrong code, so that servlet can not compile it.
it you code you have not pass the value to the method.

You are passing a string to setDep_id(),
   you will have to cast the string to integer first.

```
int depId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dep_id"))
user.setDep_id(depId );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would encounter the error earlier (he has nothing to do with servlets or HTTP status codes), if you had compiled your code first.

Comment: Please check how you compile your code before deploying and/or using it. The problem seems fairly manageable by static code analysis and therefore should fail at compile time.